# Is there a term that refers to a mapping between a person and the adjective that describes them?

Tags: terminology, anaphora

Similar to anaphora, referring to a word that refers to itself, is there a phrase for a pair consisting of a word describing a person and an adjective that describes it?

EDIT:
To clarify: In the sentence, "Harry is a gifted singer", I'm referring to the pair (Harry, gifted) specifically where Harry is the person, and gifted is the adjective, where gifted describes Harry

Comment: Noun phrase? Adjective phrase? Adjective predicate? Too many options...

Comment: @curiousdannii See my changes. I've made it more specific.

Comment: @curiousdannii Also note I want to describe the pair in itself, not just one or the other. An adjective predicate refers only to the adjective.

Comment: I'm not aware of a specific word that describes the relationship between a predicand and a dependent of the head of the related predicative complement. May I ask why it's of interest to you?

Comment: Your definition of "anaphora" isn't quite right. Anaphora is a reference to some expression elsewhere (typically preceding) in an utterance.

Comment: @BillJ I'm doing something in Natural Language Processing that uses specifically that mapping, so I was wondering if a technical term for it existed.

Comment: The concensus of opinion is that there is no spefic name for the syntactic relationship between the two elements.

Comment: @BillJ It doesn't have to by syntactic, it could be semantic as well.

Comment: There is a sematic relationship in that the predicative entails that "Harry" is gifted, and that the gift he possesses is his singing. So I suppose you could make a case for "gifted" being predicative, but predicative is a syntactic function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main point of Eleshar's answer and BillJ's comment seems to be that there is no explicit terminology because *gifted* is a modifier of the predicate *singer* rather than in direct interaction with *Harry*.
This is true syntactically:
[image]<sup>1</sup>
As expressed by the arrow labelled "amod" going from the NN *singer* to the JJ "gifted", *gifted* is an **adjectival modifier** of the noun phrase *singer*, which is itself the **subject complement** of the verb *to be* which acts as a copula between *Harry* and the noun phrase ("nsubj" = *Harry* is the "nominal subject" of the NN *singer*).
The syntactic status of *gifted* is defined with respect to the predicate *singer* which the adjective modifies, but it stands in no direct relation with *Harry*, only indirectly via the "nsub" relation from *singer* to *Harry*.
This is why it was said by others that there is no term for this kind of indirect relationship.

---

However, *semantically*, things might look differntly.
In terms of meaning, *Harry* and *gifted* do indeed stand in a relation: If Harry is a gifted singer, then this should also mean that Harry is gifted.
A classical FOL formalization would usually treat propositions of the form

> x is a ADJ NOUN

as

```
ADJ(x) ∧ NOUN(x)
```

which basically means that the predicate `ADJ` applies to x and the predicate `NOUN` applies to x.
Under this account, the adjective and the noun are treated equivalently as predications over an individual; the adjective is not a modification of *singer*, but the nominal complex *gifted singer* is viewed as a conjunction (`∧`) of two properties that apply to a certain individual `x`.
This reasoning might be easier to understand with a sentence like

> Harry is a purple zebra

```
PURPLE(harry) ∧ ZEBRA(harry)
```

where it is clear that Harry being purple is just another property that applies directly to Harry, and Harry's being a zebra is another property.<sup>2</sup>
Under this account, the adjective *gifted* is not a modifier of the subject complement *singer*, but a direct predication of *Harry*.
You could thus say that *(Harry, gifted)* is a **predication relation**: *Harry* stands in relation with *gifted* by *gifted* being a predicate over (= a property that applies to) *Harry*. To make it more precise, you can say that it is an **adjectival predication**.

---

<sup>1</sup> Image obtained from [the Stanford CoreNLP online dependency parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/corenlp/process)
<sup>2</sup> I am fully aware that this approach doesn't work for arbitrary sentences of this form; clearly, in a sentence like *Harry is an alleged murderer*, it doesn't make sense to say that *alleged* is a predicate that applies to Harry. In such a context, the adjective does act more like a modification of the property of being a murderer; in this respect, it behaves a bit like an adverb modifying the "to be" relation ("*Harry is allegedly a murdrerer*", i.e. the "to be" relation is modified in the sense that it is not necessarily true). However, in the example given, I think it's okay to say that being talented is a property that applies to Harry himself, so I'll stick to the simplistic conjunction approach.

Comment: I agree that "gifted singer" is a subjective PC, but it's a complement of the verb "be", not the subject "Harry".

Comment: @BillJ Sure, you are right. I changed it.

Comment: I disagree with the second part. *the nominal 'complex gifted singer' is viewed as a conjunction (∧) of two properties that apply to a certain individual* - *Harry* is a gifted singer* does not mean Harry is gifted and a singer, it means Harry is gifted *as* a singer (but he may be a loser otherwise). IMHO this is purely pragmatic, e.g. *Harry is a purple zebra* implies his general colour, but your own example with *alleged* reveals the necessity of applying the adjective through the noun.

Comment: @Eleshar Ah, I see your point; *Harry is a gifted singer but a terrible dancer* would be contradictory under this explanaiton. I agree that *gifted singer* is not an ideal instance of where breakig up the nominal complex into a conjunction of two predicates works . I was basing my explanation on OP's assumption that "gifted describes Harry" (which I understood as *gifted* being a property applying directly to Harry) so I'll probably leave my second part as-is for the sake of this question, but feel free to downvote if you think it's just not appropriate.

Comment: I don't understand, though, why would *Harry is a purple zebra* be purely pragmatic? I'd say that if one were to revise the analysis by somehow "applying the adjective through the noun", this should happen on the semantic level already, because general patterns of syntactic combinations (such as the composition of "x is an ADJ NOUN") shouldn't be dependent on context alone.

Comment: If Harry is a purple zebra, then he (uhm, most likely...) cannot be a red giraffe while he can be a gifted singer and a terrible dancer. So there is some semantic tie between the adjective modifying the subject complement and the subject itself (*gifted as a singer* vs *purple in general*) but its exact nature cannot be revealed without pragmatic aspects of the phrase. Albeit you might be right that this can be already defined by the combinations of the nouns (Harry can be both a singer and a dancer but not both a zebra and a giraffe) or the underlying nature of the copula.

Answer (score 4):

In your example *Harry is a gifted singer*, the word *gifted* is just a general **attribute/modifier** in an adjective phrase and there is no grammatical relation between *gifted* and *Harry* because *gifted* modifies solely the noun *singer* and is totally governed by it. I suspect that would be pretty much a universal case even in languages that employ verbs in place of adjectives and conjugate them (e.g. in *I am a gifted singer*, the verb *to be gifted* would be in 3SG and agree with *singer*).

What I suspect you are aiming at is the term **complement**, particularly **subject complement**. This is typically a simple adjective predicate like *Harry is gifted* but may be more interesting like *Harry got sick*. The general idea behind it is that it is connected to the noun typically in subject, but not as a general modifier in adjective phrase but through a transitive verb.

The subject complement is, of course, not restricted just to adjectives, e.g. in your example, the entire DP *a gifted singer* is basically a subject complement in itself.

Then there are also **object complements**, typically in some quasi-causative constructions like *This makes me sick*. Here there is a similar relationship between the adjective *sick* and the object *me*, established through the ditransitive verb *make*.